# How to send hidden PHP variable with HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I just thinking how to set and send PHP variable with HTML form, from first.php to second.php.
Actually my first code looks that:

```
<form action='add.php' method='post'> /*SOMEWHERE THERE PHP VAR*/
    <input type='text' name='account'>
    <input type='submit' value='Add'>
</form>
```

Now I just want to get it from the `first.php` file:

```
$account = addslashes($_POST['account']);
$MYPHPVAR;
```

I have tried everything: sessions, cookies, globals, everything. Still no effect.

**@EDIT**
Crap, i frogot about important.
These PHP var have to be hidden, user can't inspect it in browser.

Comment: `input type="hidden"`

Comment: Ok you've since added that it needs to be hidden form inspection. Since you can't seem to use session, encrypt it and put it in a hidden field and decrypt it when you receive it back.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a new `input` with type `hidden` within your `<form> </form>`

```
<?php $your_php_var=5;?>
</form>

    <form action='add.php' method='post'>
     <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $your_php_var; ?>">
     <input type='text' name='account'>
     <input type='submit' value='Add'>
</form>
```

See more here http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-variables.html

Comment: Value is still able to inspect by user.

Comment: @playdewu you didn't say that it had to be hidden from inspection. Please update your question.